# Critical Update - Stabilize the Hostname for My Domain URLs in Sandboxes

Tags: sandbox-refresh, mydomain, critical-update

In the critical update page it sates that - "Activating this critical update on a production org only applies the update to new and refreshed sandbox orgs."

But in the release notes it states that - "If you use service provider (SP) initiated SAML to log into your sandbox, work with your identity provider (IdP) to use the sandbox’s stabilized My Domain hostname."

Could anyone please confirm if this impacts the sandboxes that were created after summer '18 release or does it impact only the sandboxes that are crerated or refreshed after this critical update is activated.

Comment: I don't see how these are in conflict? Basically, if you turn it on in prod, any future sandboxes are affected, but those not yet activated use the old name until they are refreshed or autoactivated; check the Critical Updates Setup menu to determine when your autoactivation date is for a given sandbox.

Comment: That's my understanding as well, but the release notes is little misleading as it mentioned to test the sandboxes and for testing the sandboxes it did not mention on which ones are affected. I just activated for one of our lower instances and the existing sb is not impacted. Thank you!!